# Failed to compile vertex shader OpenGL iOS

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

I am trying to use OpenGL for the first time and I've ran into an error that I can not figure out.

I am using this code:

Here is my vertex shader code:

```
attribute vec4 position;
//attribute mediump vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;
//
//varying mediump vec2 textureCoordinate;

attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
}
```

And here is the code I am trying to load it with

```
NSString *vertShaderPathname, *fragShaderPathname;

// Create shader program.
*programPointer = glCreateProgram();

// Create and compile vertex shader.
vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:vertexShaderName ofType:@"vsh"];
if (![self compileShader:&vertexShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname])
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
```

And I get the error of `Failed to compile vertex shader` and it crashes my application. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: could you please post the code you've used for your vertex shader?

Comment: Point out first if your shader code is buggy or the shader compilation code.

Comment: @2am The first code segment is from `DrawTextureShader.vsh`. What other code are you referring to?

Comment: @Nick, SOrry, I didn't see that one. 
Try replacing line `textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;` with 
    `textureCoordinate = vec2(inputTextureCoordinate);`

Comment: I would strongly recommend to include the OpenGL-Shader compile log into your debug output. [Here is a official link](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Shader_error_handling) on how to do it.

Comment: @FelixK. I found a random project on Github that uses the same method to load the shaders, so I took my existing shaders and was able to load them in the project I found online. I think there might be a problem with the build settings in Xcode. Any ideas?

Comment: Try these 1) Print the path of the vertex shader 2) Update your question with the code you use to compile shader 3) Try GlGetError or check for shader compile log which tells you the exact error .